# Do I have to re-install the DNS server after I switch to FIOS router?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

HP ML350e - Windows server 2008 r2 - Active directory

I have put the FIOS router on the network to replace the Road runner router.

I have also restarted all the network equipments and server, but I can't access the internet.

All the computers under this domain can access the server but not internet.

Do I have to update any data on the DNS server?

Thank you.

Comment: Did lan IP address of then new router change?

Comment: They are the same, 192.168.0.1 is the gateway, 255.255.255.0 is the subnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something changed between the router swap, possibly the internal/local IP of the router as Danila mentioned. If possible compare the configuration on the two routers to verify the internal addressing settings are the same as before (external IP settings will likely be the same unless you also changed ISPs). There should be a console or intranet web interface on both routers to see detailed information such as internal IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway. Try plugging a laptop directly into the routers to get Internet working on the laptop, then change settings on the FIOS router to work with your existing internal network. You may need to contact your FIOS provider to see or change settings on their device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already compared both of the router setting, the settings are the same. I found it is funny that, it would work after I ping yahoo.com... does it make any sense that if I have the primary DNS as 192.168.0.100(the server itself, it is the AD, DNS, and file sharing server, only server) and secondary as 8.8.8.8?

Comment: does it make any sense that if I have the primary DNS as 192.168.0.100(the server itself, it is the AD, DNS, and file sharing server, only server) and secondary as 8.8.8.8? - > That is fine, only 8.8.8.8 DNS will not be able resolve local addresses if 192.168.0.100 is down.

Comment: I found the problem, it is because the forwarders still has the old DNS servers from Road Runner. I have entered the Google public dns and everything is working fine now. But am I suppose to leave the forwarders empty? Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: For any AD environment, leave the public DNS servers out of the picture with the exception of root hints. Let AD and domain controllers do all your internal DNS resolution. You only need forwarders for rare circumstances such as a DNS zone that is not known by public DNS servers. For example, if you have a persistent VPN tunnel to a vendor and in order to use a service of theirs you have to direct DNS clients to a DNS server on the other side of the tunnel. You would say for all 'vendor.zone' requests, use DNS server [vendor DNS server IP].